# C Net Adjusted, What does it mean? Should it be low or high?

Tags: tournament, statistics, pokertracker, icm

I am still pretty fuzzy on this concept of C Net Adjusted.   The answers I read are vague and I'm just looking for a simple answer.

If C Net Adjusted is lower than C Net Won (Actual), am I doing better than I should, or worse?

As far as my understanding, if C Net Adjusted is lower than C Net Won, then you are running good.   And this should be a marginal difference.

If my assumption is correct, am I also correct in assuming the stats from this run of tourny's (see image) are indicitive of a rigged poker site due to the extremely large margin between C Net Won and C Net Adjusted ?

Thanks for any help!

*9 Player $5 + $0.50 NLTH (Some are regular and some are turbo.. so 10 mins blinds and 5 min blinds)*

[image]

Comment: A few things that need to be considered... How many players in the tourneys, what game type, adjusted how (for rake or EV or...), same buy in per tourney or not, is the poker provider regulated & do they publish audited hand data? I can only hope your assumptions are based on data and not how you feel. 30 or so tourneys isn't even enough to make fair assumptions about heads up tourneys.

Comment: Its all 9 player single table ..  $5 buyin ... Turbo mostly, some regs.  The statistic is from Poker Tracker (tagged in my question and on the chart in the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the "Adjusted" description relates to a calculation involving ICM.

Ripped direct from the PT4 forums, posted by the mod WhiteRider: (See the whole thread [here](https://pt4.pokertracker.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=49822))

> "My C" means "My Currency", and implies a monetary stat.
>
> "My C Net Adjusted" is your expected winnings based on the difference
>   in ICM values between your actual chip stack at the end of a
>   hand and the all-in equity adjusted chip stack you "should have had"
>   at the end of the hand; for all all-in hands in a tournament. This
>   calculation uses every all-in hand in a STT and final table hands from
>   MTTs where we know the complete payout structure.

With regard to your graph, this means that eventually the two lines will converge. In the short term, it's an indication of how above, or below average, your luck is.

This is as comprehensive an explanation of what it means as you'll find I believe. Direct from the developer.

Comment: So have I been having good luck or bad ?

Comment: It would seem based on your current graph you've been having good luck up until now. Inevitably you'll have a period of bad luck in the future, and eventually your luck will be average just like everybody else in the world, ever (on average). ;)

Comment: darn i was hoping i was having bad luck haha

Comment: with that _30-only sample_ you can safely assume nothing ;)

Comment: I wonder how you're doing today?

Comment: @Jonast92 Why would you be wondering how I am doing?

Comment: Meant to be a comment targeted at @TechSavant

Comment: @Jonast92 ahhhhh ok. I agree, would be good to know.